# any way to figure out when hd processing is done with youtube data api v3?

Tags: rest, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I can't figure out how to tell when a video is done with *all* processing after it's been uploaded with the youtube data api v3.  I query the video and look at the processingDetails.processingStatus and it's 'succeeded', the contentDetails.definition is 'hd', but the video is still processing the HD version in the Channel content dashboard on youtube; it seems these returns from the API flip to succeeded as soon as the SD version is processed.

[image: Still processing HD]

As far as I can tell this isn't covered anywhere in the docs, and I can't find anything online about it.  If it matters, this video is being exported from twitch to youtube, but that shouldn't matter (edit: it doesn't matter, acts the same on uploads), it acts just like an uploaded video once it shows up in the yt dashboard.

Here's the struct that should return 'processing':  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#processingDetails.processingStatus

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Chris

PS.  This is also true for the new 'checking' status for copyright stuff, it appears this doesn't show up in the api, but since it happens after SD but before HD, if I could just get the HD processing status that'd cover it unless the order changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I tested, there isn't much difference when using [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) on a video before it got its HD processing completed and after it got completed.

The single difference I observed is that the `maxres` key is added to `item["snippet"]["thumbnails"]` when the HD processing got completed. I think you can use this to know whether or not your video got its HD processing completed.

Comment: Ah, I looked for stuff like this but didn't notice that, I'll give it a shot and report back, thanks!

Comment: This appears to work.  I don't know if it would work for a video with only SD resolutions less than 720p, I didn't test one but those might still be checking when maxres is set, but for 720p+ videos it seems to work, so thanks.  Google should fix this for real, but this is a good workaround.

Comment: Glad to have helped :)